Thingsboard and exotel connection
{
    "Body": "This is a Security Alert message:-55 : - Security Engineers Pvt. Ltd",
    "DltEntityId": "12011****1088652",
    "DltTemplateId": "170717*****237024",

    "From": "SE**M",
    "To": "+91800000004",
    "error": "class org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.WebClientResponseException$BadRequest: 400 Bad Request from POST https://api.exotel.com/v1/Accounts/sep55/Sms/send.json",
    "error_body": "{\"RestException\":{\"Status\":400,\"Message\":\"Message body cannot be empty.\",\"Code\":40200}}\n",
    "status": "Bad Request", 

I got this error when I try to sent post request from thingsboard to exotel, but I also in body write message. Can anyone help me?
I also sent exact message in body but got an error.
